# .NetCore API Version problem with SwaggerUI

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I have been following [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/SwaggerSample) to implement versioning on an API and I am using header versioning. After swapping my useSwaggerUI code with the samples I no longer get a swagger UI:

[image]

When I debug through the following:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    //options.DocumentTitle = "Web API Core";
    //options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebAPICore V1");
    //options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "WebAPICore V2");
    //options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
    {
 options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
    }
});
```

it appears that the SwaggerEndpoint call formats the url the same as the commented url. I have obviously missed something or this has moved on a little bit and I need to do something a little different. Is anyone able to advise here please?

- .Net Core 2.2
- .Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 4.01

[edit - more info] When I run this now and see the SwaggerUI as described I can use Postman to hit the endpoint and the header versioning works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. While working through it I was also using other sites to help some of the problems I was having and it turns out that the line:

```
options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, description) => true);
```

in the AddSwaggerGen method. Getting rid of it and I have the Swagger ui back.